# Leaflet R color map based on multiple variables?

Tags: r, leaflet

From what I have seen colored maps in leaflet usually only depict one variable(GDP, Crime stats, Temperature etc) like this one:

[image: one]. 
Is there a way to make maps that display the highest variable in a data frame in leaflet R? For example showing which alcoholic beverage is the most popular in a country, like this map?

[image: this]
<sub>(source: [dailymail.co.uk](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2011/02/17/article-1357892-0D3BD418000005DC-958_972x546.jpg))</sub>

Say that I had a data frame that looked like this and I wanted to do a similar map to the alcoholic beverage one...

```
Country  Beer Wine Spirits Coffee Tea  
Sweden     7   7      5      10    6
USA        9   6      6       7    5
Russia     5   3      9       5    8
```

Is there a way in leaflet R to pick out the alcoholic beverages, assign them a color and then display them on the map to show which type of alcoholic beverage is the most popular in the three different countries?

Comment: can you share your dataset (use dput()) and code so we can help you?

Comment: You don't do this in leaflet, you do it in R. Just use R to create a new categorical column which is the name of the column with the biggest value (what if there's a tie?). Once that's done its straightforward to map it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step 0, make a test data frame:

```
> set.seed(1234)
> drinks = data.frame(Country=c("Sweden","USA","Russia"),
     Beer=sample(10,3), Wine=sample(10,3), Spirits=sample(10,3),
     Coffee=sample(10,3), Tea=sample(10,3))
```

Note I have country as a column - yours might have countries in the row names which means the following code needs changing. Anyway. We get:

```
> drinks
  Country Beer Wine Spirits Coffee Tea
1  Sweden    2    7       1      6   3
2     USA    6    8       3      7   9
3  Russia    5    6       6      5  10
```

Now we combine `apply` to work along rows, `which.max` to get the highest element, and various subset operations to drop the country column and get the drink name from the column names:

```
> drinks$Favourite = names(drinks)[-1][apply(drinks[,-1],1,which.max)]
> drinks
  Country Beer Wine Spirits Coffee Tea Favourite
1  Sweden    2    7       1      6   3      Wine
2     USA    6    8       3      7   9       Tea
3  Russia    5    6       6      5  10       Tea
```

If there's a tie then `which.max` will pick (I think) the first element. If you want something else then you'll have to rewrite.

Now feed your new data frame to leaflet and map the `Favourite` column.